# How to check for a whole number?

Tags: c++, casting

I am learning C++ and checking if the input is a prime number. I can't have anything complicated since this is for a stubborn teacher in a beginner's course. Each if-statement runs except the first one, where it checks if `userInput` is a whole number. Here is my program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int userInput;
    bool isPrime = true;
    
    while (true){
        cout << "Enter a number to check if it is a prime number: ";
        cin >> userInput;
    
        if (floor(userInput) != ceil(userInput)){
            cout << "Please type a whole number.\n\n";
            continue;
        } else if (userInput == 1){
            cout << "This is not a prime number!\n\n";
            continue;
        } else if (userInput <= 0){
            cout << "Please type a postive integer.\n\n";
            continue;
        }

        for (int i = 2; i <= sqrt(userInput); ++i) {
            if (userInput % i == 0) {
                isPrime = false;
                break;
            } else {
                isPrime = true;
            }
        }
   
        if (isPrime){
            cout << userInput << " is a prime number.\n\n";
        } else {
            cout << userInput << " is not a prime number!\n\n";
        }

        cin.clear();                                                // clears errors if input generated error flags so the program can successfully wait for user
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');        // clears the input buffer by ignoring all (max) characters
        cout << "Press Enter to continue...";    
        cin.get();                                                  // gets the key that was pressed
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried the following code as the condition in that specific if-statement but the terminal always just outputs "(double that was casted to int) is not a prime number!)

- `userInput != (int)userInput`
- `floor(userInput) != ceil(userInput)`
- `userInput != (int)userInput`
- `userInput == (double)userInput   //prints "Enter a number to check if it is a prime number:     Please type a whole number.`
- `userInput != static_cast<int>(userInput)   //prints "Enter a number to check if it is a prime number:     Please type a whole number.`
- `floor(userInput) != userInput`
- `modf(castedUserInput, &intpart) == 0.0 // declared two double variables earlier: double castedUserInput = (double)userInput;   and double intpart;     -prints "Enter a number to check if it is a prime number:    Please type a whole number`

It's obvious some of these should work, so what's wrong with the rest of my code? Also off the topic, but is `continue` the wrong key word to use in the if-statements if I still want the user to be prompted with the "Please Enter to continue..." at the end? As expected, the whole loop just restarts, but I want it to reach the end of the while loop.

**Teacher's instructions:**

- Write a program that asks the user for whole integers.
- Read the input.
- Check if it is a positive integer number. keep on asking the user for
  a positive integer number till the user gives you a positive integer
  number. Make sure you catch the characters.
- Check if the variable is a prime number, display your answer with the
  corresponding validation as shown on the sample executable file.
- Tell the User to hit Enter to run the program again.
- Observe the good programming practices and the structure of a
  program.
- Do not forget the comments, halt the screen, spacing of code and
  output, make it release etc.
- For the title of the program use the "what you see is what you get
  approach" (only one cout statement in multiple lines).

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: @user12002570 I have tried using a debugger, but it only prints out the expression inside the code and all of the options I wrote down would just give me the "userInput is not a prime number!" at the end

Comment: For a more efficient algorithm, check out [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

Comment: @JesperJuhl I would love to dive into deciphering that Wikipedia page, but my teacher doesn't like us "going ahead". Thank you, though.

Comment: `userInput` is an `int`. There is no "double that was casted to int" and its unclear what you expect from `floor(userInput) != ceil(userInput)`

Comment: "I have tried the following code as the condition in that specific if-statement..." to do what? To check that the user did enter an integer? `userInput` can only be an integer. If the user entered something else `std::cin` is in an error state, but there is no way to tell that from looking at `userInput`

Comment: A whole number is just a non-negative integer.   You're already declaring `userInput` as an integer (with `int userInput`), so it can't store a fractional number with digits after the decimal place (e.g. 3.14) so you can check to see if it is a whole number by checking `if (userInput >= 0)`  Note that later you also check to see if it is strictly **positive** so the entire "whole number" check is likely redundant. Seems like you intended to check "is it an integer" - and it **is** by definition, by virtue of its declared type.

Comment: Please remove `using namespace std;`. (That is one of the **first** things that a stubborn teacher in a beginner course should have told you.) In your code, what do you expect `floor()` and `ceil()` to do to an integer? Your integer is converted to a `float` or `double` (the argument type), then the function is applied to the outcome, which yields the same integer if the floating-point number’s density suffices, and may yield a slightly lower or higher integer in case the integer falls into the low-density range(s) of floating-point numbers, which may fail to represent all integers precisely.

Comment: You probably need to input a double instead of an int and do your floor/ceil stuff with that double. The once you've detected that the double is a whole number assign it to an int and proceed with that int. But are you really required to check if the input is a whole number? You should post the exact requirement in the question.

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek In my first projects, I did not have ```using namespace std;``` and the teacher marked me off for writing everything with ```std::```. And I completely missed the fact that ```floor()``` and ```ceil()``` were used only for floats and doubles. My mind was thinking that the if-statement would only run if I the value were a double or float, my bad!

Comment: @WolfHasQuack you obviously have a terrible teacher...

Comment: @Jabberwocky 1.9 rating on RateMyProfessors!

Comment: @WolfHasQuack 1.9, that explains it.

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek I'll implement the ```namespace { using std::cout; using std::cin; }``` this time, thank you! If she says anything, I'll be sure to use this explanation.

Comment: More details on why `using namespace std;` is best avoided can be found in [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: Did your professor tell you to check whether user input is an integer? If so, did he explain how to perform the check?

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI I posted the teacher's instructions on my question just now. It says to ask the user for a whole integer, but not exactly how. We are learning about while loops and for loops this week.

Comment: The assignment says "Make sure you catch the characters". I'm not quite sure what this means, but if I had to guess, I would say that you are supposed to input a *string* and check if that string contains a positive integer.